# Is there a way to use the last entered input in Python like in a shell?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI of sorts that works like a shell. I have a function that listens for user input and executes functions based on it.

I want to have it so that you can click the UP arrow key to use the last entered command. I'm guessing you could keep a record of entered commands and refer to it when Python detects the pressing of the UP arrow key, but is there a way of doing this that's not keeping an array? That seems kind of hacky.

Comment: Use an array as a stack and simply add each input one by one. When the user press up, display the last element (element -1). If the user press up many time, count this time (e.g. in a variable `i`) and display the element `-i`. I don't know any structure specially dedicated to the thing you want to do.

Comment: If you want something like auto completetion on previous commands, I suppose you could use a trie. See this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/auto-complete-feature-using-trie/ .

Comment: I see. Well, that should work nicely anyways. Thank you both!